# How to export EXPLAIN data Output from pgAdmin 4

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin, pgadmin-4

I am working on postgresql , with pgAdmin 4 . I am trying to do some query performance optimizations. 
When I run a query with EXPLAIN ANALYZE (or) EXPLAIN (VERBOSE TRUE) , the 'Data Output' I see is shown in the following screenshot. 
[image]

How to get output for EXPLAIN ANALYZE(or export my current 'Data Ouput') in this format, which I can input into http://explain.depesz.com  :

```
QUERY PLAN
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Sort  (cost=29.71..29.73 rows=6 width=64) (actual time=0.189..16.233 rows=7 loops=1)
   Sort Key: books.title
   ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.00..29.63 rows=6 width=64) (actual time=0.068..0.129 rows=7 loops=1)
         ->  Index Scan using authors_pkey on authors  (cost=0.00..5.82 rows=1 width=36) (actual time=0.029..0.033 rows=1 loops=1)
               Index Cond: (id = 16)
         ->  Seq Scan on books  (cost=0.00..23.75 rows=6 width=36) (actual time=0.026..0.052 rows=7 loops=1)
               Filter: (author_id = 16)
 Total runtime: 16.386 ms
```

Comment: 5 years later and I wasn't able to do it in this screen.
Instead, I went to the query screen and wrote EXPLAIN ANALYSE before my query and ran it.    Then go to the data output select the first cell, and highlight all cells (Ctrl-A) then press CTRL-C to copy them.
You can then paste this into explain.depesz

Answer (score 1):

Use built-in explain option of pgAdmin4 to get your desired output.

[image]

And now you can copy the output from 'Data ouput' tab.

Comment: Did you check what you really got in the output file?

Comment: I am getting json explain output, which the tool mentioned is question is not accepting

Comment: @Murtuza Z...You saved my time and it helped me in copying explain plan. Thanks